# Check for Time - get-date PowerShell

Tags: powershell, time

I have a task in PowerShell and want to check the time while the process is running.
if it passes 8:05 am I want stop the process.  How can I achieve this in PowerShell?

Thanks in advance.

```
$time = get-date -Format hh:mm
$time
if ($time > 8:05)
{
   Write-Output "passed 8:05 am"
   exit
}
else
{
   Write-Output "too early"
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Does your code not work as expected? What's your problem with your code snippet?

Comment: Is this "task" implemented in PowerShell and this code will be part of it, or is it run as a job, process, something else?  In the latter case you'd check the time in a loop and see if it has passed 8:05 AM; if it has, abort the task, otherwise sleep for a period before checking again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with date format and date comparisons in PowerShell is, that they are annoying as hell.

The easiest way is to define two variables, one for the time at the moment:

```
$timenow = get-date
```

And one for the set time:

```
$timecomparison = Get-Date -Hour 8 -Minute 5
```

Then, for the actual comparison, you need to use the Get-Date parameter "timeofday":

```
If ($timenow.TimeOfDay -lt $timecomparison.TimeOfDay) {do something}
```

Also, please correct me if I am wrong, but in Powershell operators like >,<,= tend to not work properly in conditions and loops. That is why I prefer to use "larger than" `-lt`

Comment: Thanks Bowshock.  The time is in 24-hour format (Get-Date -Hour 8 -Minute 5) which will work.  Just curious, is there a PowerShell syntax to get this in 12 hour?

Comment: Note when passing date/time component values to `Get-Date` they override those components of the _current_ time.  Therefore, if at 12:34:56.789 PM you call `Get-Date -Hour 8 -Minute 5` the resulting `DateTime` will have a `TimeOfDay` component of `08:05:56.7890000` — nearly 57 seconds later than the intended time.  To get it to be exactly 8:05 AM you have to specify _all_ of the time components with `Get-Date -Hour 8 -Minute 5 -Second 0 -Millisecond 0`.  My comment on the other answer shows another way to get 8:05 AM, and `[DateTime] '8:05 AM'` works, too, at least in the `en-US` culture.

Comment: To avoid confusion:  "-lt"  means "less than" not "larger than".  If you are looking for something like "larger than" you should use "-gt", which means "greater than".

Answer (score -1):

you need to convert the "time" variable to double format because the default is string, and replace ':' with '.'

```
$time = get-date -Format hh.mm
$time.replace('.',':')
$double = [double]$time
if ($double -ge 8.05)
{
   Write-Output "passed 8:05 am"
   exit
}
else
{
   Write-Output "too early"
}
```

I also advise you to read the syntax of the comparison
 [in powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: The syntax errors in the question suggest the author doesn't know how to compare times, so instead of doing a literal translation of their mistakes you might as well simplify it to `$now = Get-Date; if ($now -ge $now.Date.AddHours(8).AddMinutes(5)) { # ...`.  That still doesn't handle the case where the next 8:05 AM occurs _tomorrow_ (since they haven't specified when the task begins or how long it takes to complete).

Comment: As far as I understand it is about 8 am and not 8 hours of code execution, therefore adding to the current time will be incorrect.

Comment: `$now.Date` gives midnight of today.  Midnight + 8 hours + 5 minutes gives 8:05 AM today.  Also, your cast to `[Double]` would work if not for replacing `.` with `:`, which won't parse.  Another way to compare the current hours as a `[Double]` would be `(Get-Date).TimeOfDay.TotalHours -ge 8.05`.